# MS Access comboboxes and NVDA

Tags: ms-access, combobox, accessibility, nvda

I'm working on a library system in MS Access 2010. One of the challenges is that we have blind and other visually impaired users accessing the system.

They use NVDA, a screen reading software, and the issue is that the software doesn't read the content of comboboxes straight away. To get around this, one would have to press CAPSLOCK+UP or INSERT+UP (NVDA commands) which read the current line in focus. So they are currently doing this line by line manually to know where they are.

I thought of automating this through Sendkeys, but as far as I know there is no way to combine keys other than Alt, Shift and Ctrl. This is a small piece of code I'm using just so that down key drops down the combobox:

```
Private Sub Username_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)

If KeyCode = vbKeyDown Then 
Me.ActiveControl.Dropdown 
End If

End Sub
```

I would like to add to this code so that the pressing of Up and Down keys trigger the reading of the combobox through Sendkeys of INSERT+UP or perhaps some other way I'm not aware. Is this possible? Any ideas?

Comment: You know about the character shorthand for alternative keys, correct?

Comment: good explanation of the basic syntax: https://www.contextures.com/excelvbasendkeys.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I know the shorthand keys, but with Sendkeys you can only combine Alt, Shift or Ctrl. If I put something like {INSERT}{UP}, it triggers one and then the other and I don't get the result I want. Perhaps there really is no way to do it with Sendkeys or SendInput, I don't know, but since I imagine others would also like to combine different keys, someone may have a work around for this issue

Comment: Just me typing outloud....have you considered that you are maybe asking Access, or even VBA, to perform an action it is not necessarily able to perform?  I have rarely found myself using INSERT as a control key, like Shift, Ctrl, and Alt.  {INSERT} has an O/S-based operational function.  Which is why it is generally not used as a control key.  As a vice, Shift/Ctrl/Alt are application specific and have no real O/S specified function; aside, Windows uses Ctrl as a Login function but only during login.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if the right question is being asked.  It sounds like a problem in Access that you're trying to work around.  I'm not familiar with Access itself (so I probably shouldn't be commenting) but I **am** very familiar with accessibility.

Are you tabbing to a checkbox in a cell, or a checkbox that is in a popup dialog such as when you sort a column and want to select/deselect some of the filters?  Is the problem that the checkbox itself does not have a label to be read, or that it does have a label but the label can only be read using a "read all" shortcut key (such as ins+down) or "read current" (ins+up)?

To put this in html terms, the follow code will display a checkbox that **visually** appears like the checkbox has a label, but the screen reader does not know there is a label.

```html
<input type="checkbox">Do you feel well today?
```

The screen reader will just say "checkbox".  However, if you tie the label to the checkbox using the `<label>` element

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheck"><label for="mycheck">Do you feel well today?</label>
```

then the screen reader **does** know the checkbox has a label and will say "Do you feel well today?, checkbox, not checked".

I know that's a tangent from the original question, but I'm wondering if you are creating a checkbox in Access or if you are trying to navigate to a checkbox that natively exists in Access (such as the sort dialog).  If you are creating a checkbox, then similar to how you have to associate a label with a checkbox in html, I wonder if there's a way to associate a label with a checkbox in Access.  If so, then you wouldn't need your workaround.

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for your attention. Though I think you must have misread me, it's not a checkbox, it's a combobox. That is, a drop down menu with a list of items in several rows. In Access, it's called a control and it was created by me to be worked inside a form. NVDA reads Access textboxes and labels quite well. The combobox itself has a name(sorta works like a html label) "Username" and this is also read. But the various lines of content inside the Username control combobox are not read automatically and that's my issue, so the labeling is not the matter.

Comment: ah crap, you're right.  i saw 'combobox' and my brain said 'checkbox'.  when the dropdown is displayed, you want all the values read?  typically, as a screen reader arrows up/down through the list, it reads just that one value.