# Need accessibility related help for VBA generated combo box

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, accessibility, excel-2007

I've created a combo box in Excel (using VBA and UserForm). The combo box contains several options, but when navigating to any of those options, the screen reader does not announce the value of the focused option. The widget was primarily created to be used by screen reader users, and its inaccessibility raises significant concerns.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Turn on the screen reader (NVDA or Narrator).
2. Navigate to the combo box using the 'Tab' or 'Shift + Tab' keys.
3. Expand the combo box.
4. Press the 'Down' arrow key. The focus moves to the next option, but the screen reader remains silent.

This issue can be replicated on any VBA combo box.

Any help or guidance will be highly appreciated!

I tried changing the style to "0 drop down combo" and other, but nothing worked.

Comment: Have you seen this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52193163/ms-access-comboboxes-and-nvda